# Passport control when flying from Romania to Italy

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, passport-stamps

Do you guys know if there is passport control and stamp when flying from Romania to Milan-Italy?

I would like to know that because I need to get my passport stamped in Italy.

Answer (score 8):

Romania has not yet been integrated into the Schengen border-control-free travel area, so there will be passport control between Romania and Italy.

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area

http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/index_en.htm

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you have to go through immigration and passport control when flying from Romania to Italy, but your passport will only be stamped if your are a non-EU/EEA citizen. If you e.g. have a Romanian passport, your passport will not be stamped when entering Italy.

Comment: Note that this answer might be misunderstood. Romanian citizens are not  necessarily required to have a passport to enter Italy, a national ID card is sufficient.

Comment: @vsz I am not sure why that should be misunderstood. It is also not relevant to the question asked, wether Romanian citizens can use their national id card as a travel document when entering Italy.

Comment: People might get the idea that the passports are mandatory.

Comment: @vsz for non-EU/EEA citizens, passports *are* mandatory.  (I presume the OP is a non-EU/EEA citizen because of the requirement to have a passport stamp.)

Comment: @phoog : you are right, nowhere in the question says the OP is a Romanian citizen, just that the flight starts in Romania. From all we know the OP might have started the journey literally anywhere. But still, *"If you e.g. have a Romanian passport, your passport will not be stamped when entering Italy."* might give the impression that Romanian citizens are required to have a passport to enter Italy.